# Floating dropdown in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to click in a cell, a drop down appears, then whichever choice is made from the dropdown store that value.  I made the dropdown and can place it on a cell but I have a lot of cell that need this dropdown and it looks real ugly with all the dropdown arrows.

Comment: could you please specify what software/tool you are talking about?

Comment: What are you talking about? Are you programming? Are you working with excel? Provide more info on the matter please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Superuser...  My question relates to Excel 2007. We need a floating dropdown that can plug the result the user picks into the cell on the spread sheet.  I was thinking that if the user clicks on a cell (A1) then the dropdown would come up.  The user picks from the dropwdown, the value is then saved in A1.  Then the user moves onto B1 and the process repeats.

Comment: I have updated title and tags to include Excel

Answer (score 2):

Use Excel's Data Validation feature to create dropdowns in cells.  I suggest reading the following tutorial:

http://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html